# How to calculate the likelihood of a sentence using a Word2Vec model?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I need to train a Word2Vec model, which I have done, and then I need to use it to calculate the likelihood of previously unseen data. I'm stuck on how to do this though. I've seen WMD but that's for calculating similarity between 2 sentences, while I'm trying to calculate the likelihood of text with my model.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question should have your effort to solve the task. Here you post abstract question which people will likely delete rather answer it. Code is good, environment, screenshots, error codes if any. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).